# PowerShell calculating prime factors

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that calculates the prime factors of all numbers lower than X (in this example 1 million).  The code is very very simple and I think easy to understand but I can't seem to find out why it is not working.

```
where ($number -lt 1000000) {
    where ($number2 -lt $number) {
       if (($number % $number2) -eq 0) {
            Write-Host number $number prime $number2 >> C:\workspace\output.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `where` like a while loop from the looks of it and you do not change the values of `$number` or `$number2`. Might be easier if you look at the [`for` block](http://ss64.com/ps/for.html) for your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where ($number -lt 1000000) {
    where ($number2 -lt $number) {
       if (($number % $number2) -eq 0) {
            Write-Host number $number prime $number2 >> C:\workspace\output.txt
        }
        $number++
    }
}
```

You need to increment $number in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the problem - this script / function returns the factors of the number

Optimisations

1. Handle 2 as a prime first
2. Then only brute force odd numbers
3. Stop when the factor to test exceeds the square root of the number, or the remaining quotient is less than the square root of the number

```
Function Factorise {
    PARAM ($Number)

    $MaxFactor = [math]::Sqrt($Number)

    #take care of 2 as a factor
    $Factor=2
    while ( ($Number % $Factor) -eq 0) {
        $Factor
        $Number=$Number/$Factor
    }

    #then brute force all odd numbers as factors up to max prime
    #while $Number remains greater than max prime
    $Factor=3
    while ($Factor -le $MaxFactor -and $number -ge $MaxFactor) {
        while ( ($Number % $Factor) -eq 0) {
            $Factor
            $Number=$Number/$Factor
        }
        $Factor+=2
    }
    $Number
}
```

Sample output

```
Factorise 32770
2
5
29
113
```

Answer (score 0):

You were both right.  I was missing the `$number = $number + 1`.  I was able to figure it out after a few more hours.

```
#setup
$number = 1
$number2 = 1

while ($number -le 1000000)
{
    while ($number2 -le $number)
    {
        if (($number % $number2) -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host $number and $number2
        }
        $number2 = $number2 + 1
    }
    $number2 = 1
    $number = $number + 1
}
```